# AngularJS: How to recompile on data change on a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement lightSlider (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) on a popup window which can be opened when the user click on an image.

There are many images on a page and each one can open a popup with a lightSlider. The contents of the gallery is different each time.

The problem is that lightGallery wraps the element div with a lot of extra div elements. So each time "media" is changed, I need to find a way to delete the whole element and create a new one from the template and run lightGallery on it.

Little help please...

Thanks!

```
App.directive('lightGallery', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            media: '='
        },
        compile: function CompilingFunction($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
            $('.lSSlideOuter').remove();
            $templateElement.replaceWith(this.template);
            return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
                    gallery:true,
                    item:1,
                    thumbItem:9,
                    slideMargin:0,
                    currentPagerPosition:'center'
                });
            };
        },
        template: '<ul id="imageGallery">'+
                    '<li ng-repeat="item in media.media" data-thumb="{{item.picture}}" data-src="{{item.source}}">'+
                        '<img src="{{item.source}}" />'+
                    '</li>'+
                  '</ul>'
    }
});
```